# Device doesn't render in Design tab, Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem with my `Android Studio` I just updated. 
There is no device renders in the `design tab`, even if I create just a blank aka 'hello wolrd' activity as you can see on this [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aig3fo0jtvr9f75/android.png?dl=0).
I am absolutely sure I have no running background tasks, my `Gradle` build is finished. I tried to clean up and then to rebuild project, nothing changes. Am I missing anything?
P.S. I had no problems rendering device on `Android Studio 1.3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it.
I had to update my SDK to 23st version and choose this version while rendering device.
Very simple and truth be told obvious way.